# RSS Comment Feeds from SharePoint 2007 Blog

Tags: rss, sharepoint, blogging, sharepoint-2007

Is there any way to subscribe to RSS comment feeds from a SharePoint 2007 blog?
Or to include comments in the standard RSS feed? Some easy way to be notified or new comments to a thread via RSS?

Answer (score 1):

Sharepoint is pretty limited and it does not follow standards like most blogs, so out of the box without more tweaking / work arounds you cannot just consume an RSS/XML feed for comments.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to find a way to use the Content Query Web Part (Publishing Feature required) - it has an option to publish an RSS feed of its query results.